# Not the content but the -mission

Tags: word

```
 HOW  HE  PRINTED  MY ID  NOW

 MAN  LIVES AT MY  RES

 ONE  AWFUL TRIVIA   END  IT

 AN  EX  IS  AT  END

 GO ON  SAL  DO  WIN 
 
 GO  ON A MISSION STAN
```

Can you solve this word riddle?

Note: All formatting intentional.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is

> SOLVED

by finding a

> letter which completes the words on each line:
>
>  **S**HOW SHE  SPRINTED [MYSID](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mysid) SNOW
>  **O**MAN OLIVES [ATOMY](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/atomy)  ORES
>  **L**ONE LAWFUL TRIVIAL  LEND  LIT
>  **V**AN VEX VIS VAT VEND
>  **E**GO ONE SALE DOE WINE
>  GO**D** DON ADMISSION STAND

Title

> Clues an omission.

Comment: Good job! I'm not OP, but two small notes: rot13(Gurer vf ab oynax orsber 'BA' va ebj 5, gur oynax vf nsgre vg. Fb vg fubhyq or 'BAR' abg 'RBA'. Fvzvyneyl, va ebj 6 gurer vf n oynax orsber 'TB', naq bayl 1 oynax orgjrra 'TB' naq 'BA. 'TBQ QBA' erdhverf gjb oynaxf orgjrra gurz, naq qbrfa'g fngvfsl gur oynax orsber 'TB'. Ohg znlor ebj 6 vf na reebe sebz BC? Znlor gurl vagraqrq ab oynax orsber 'TB' naq gjb oynaxf orgjrra 'TB' naq 'BA'?)

Comment: Thanks SpiritFryer for noticing one much better fit - updated now. Also good point on line 6, maybe DrD will say!

Comment: All Good Comments. Also @Tom did you notice the title? -mission?